# Maven, SNAPSHOT artifact has strange suffix

Tags: maven, maven-2, dependencies

I found next artifact in repo that am using.
artifact contains in

```
/com  
+/company  
++/web-services    
+++/wsdls  
++++/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  
+++++/wsdls-1.0.0-20121119.140914-5-wsdl.zip
```

strange **-wsdl** in artifact name
I try use

```
<groupId>com.company.web-services</groupId>
<artifactId>wsdls</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<type>zip</type>
```

but this search artifact **wsdls-1.0.0-20121119.140914-5.zip** in repo but not  **wsdls-1.0.0-20121119.140914-5-wsdl.zip**.
How can I get this artifact?

PS. `maven-metadata.xml`

```
<metadata>
 <groupId>com.company.web-services</groupId>
   <artifactId>wsdls</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <versioning>
     <snapshot>
      <timestamp>20121119.140914</timestamp>
      <buildNumber>5</buildNumber>
     </snapshot>
     <lastUpdated>20121119140914</lastUpdated>
   </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is **classifier**, one of five artifact coordinates:

- groupId
- artifactId
- version
- classifier
- type

It is `null` (empty) by default. When present, a dash is prepended to it when constructing filename.

Frequently used classifiers are:

- sources
- test
- javadoc

plus, of course, any custom classifiers.

In your case, you should write your dependency like this:

```
<groupId>com.company.web-services</groupId>
<artifactId>wsdls</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<classifier>wsdl</classifier>
<type>zip</type>
```